# make: g++ command not found error with makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm writing a makefile like so:

```
LIB_DIR = $(shell pwd)/.linuxbrew/Cellar/boost/1.62.0/

FLAGS = -std=c++14

INC= -I$(LIB_DIR)include
LIB_PATH = -L$(LIB_DIR)lib
LIB = $(LIB_DIR)lib

LIBNAMES := filesystem-mt filesystem system-mt system

LIBS := $(foreach N,$(LIBNAMES),$(LIB)libboost_$N.a $(LIB)libboost_$N.dylib)

PATH = /Some/Path/

default:
        g++ main.cpp $(FLAGS) $(INC) $(LIB_PATH) $(LIBS) -o assemble
        ./assemble $(PATH)

clean:
        rm assemble
```

The problem is, once I include the variable 'LIB_DIR', it complains that g++ can't be found. I could use some help.

Comment: Please show exactly what you mean by "include the variable 'LIB_DIR'" and also show the exact command that make invoked when you ran it and the error message you get.  Also, there's really no point in doing this with a makefile, as you have it.  You're not using any features of make: you're just compiling everything every time.  Why not just write a shell script that contains the compile line and be done with it?

Comment: For practice. This works fine if I remove LIB_DIR. I need to use PATH because I pass a directory with execution to access it's contents. When I remove LIB_DIR, it works fine on my machine (which is the intent). I include LIB_DIR because on a remote machine, this is the location of Boost libraries.

Comment: OK, but it's not much of a practice if you don't actually do anything remotely related to make's capabilities, other than setting variables.

Comment: Sure, but I had to practice just to get that setup! Ha. So how do I set it to access the path to Boost libraries on a remote machine?

Comment: make and the compiler don't know anything about remote machines.  Do you mean through a mounted filesystem like NFS?  Make allows you to run the same commands that you could type at a shell prompt, in a reproducible way in the right order.  So if you can write a command (like a compile operation) at the shell prompt, then you can get make to do that for you instead.  If you can't write a command at the shell prompt to do what you want, then make can't do it either.

Comment: I can cd into a directory from the shell? I can locate path to a library from the shell?

Comment: I don't understand your questions.  Obviously you can cd into a directory.  I don't know what you mean by "locate path to a library"; locate how?  You understand by "the shell" I'm talking about the program you type commands into, like when you type "make" at the command prompt.  The shell is the program that prints that command prompt and interprets and executes the commands you type there.  In any event, StackOverflow is not the right place for these fundamental questions: it's supposed to answer specific detailed questions not be a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

It's not `LIB_DIR`, but rather `PATH` that's killing you.  Try commenting out that line.   (I'm assuming g++ is not in /Some/Path/)

Comment: I pass path with the executable bc part of my program processes files within a directory.

Comment: You can't use a variable named `PATH`, is what John is saying.  The `PATH` variable is used by the shell to store locations where all the programs it wants to run (like your compiler) live.  If you reset that variable in the makefile, you're overriding that.  Change the variable name `PATH` to something else like `APP_PATH` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command:

```
yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```

The command install all development tools like `make`, `gcc`, etc.